# android DCIM path for html

Tags: php, android, html

We are trying to minimize data usage for our systems.
The idea is to have a website that is live and to link to any resources such as video locally on the device.

Here is a snipped of what is trying to be acheived:

```
<html>
<head>Test</head>
<body>
  <img src="/storage/emulated/0/images/star.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

Is it even possible to host video and images locally on a device that a website can link to?
Everything that I have read about tells me that this is a poor idea or may not be entirely possible without creating a java app first to get the path.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to accomplish this. The device security does not allow this.